# angular 2 hide or show child component

Tags: angular

I have a "parent" component whose template includes two other components. I want to show or hide either component somehow. I looked at the [multiple component angular.io tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html) to try and figure this out but nothing is happening (and no console errors are coming up).

My "parent" component with it's template is:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'main-area',
    templateUrl: 'main-area.html',
    directives: [Child1Component, Child2Component]
})
export class MainComponent {
        child1Shown:boolean = true;
        child2Shown:boolean = false;
}
```

main-area.html -

```
<div>
    <childOne [hidden]="child1Shown"></childOne>
    <childTwo [hidden]="child2Shown"></childTwo>
</div>
```

My child components each have a template but here are what the code looks like in them.

Child1:

```
@Component({
    selector:'childOne',
    templateUrl: 'childOne.html'     
})    

export class Child1Component { 
   @Input() hidden:boolean;
}
```

Child2:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'childTwo',
    templateUrl: 'childTwo.html'
})

export class Child2Component {
        @Input() hidden:boolean;
}
```

When the page loads with it's `MainComponent` child2 should be hidden (with it's template) and child1 shown (with it's template). However both are being shown. I've tried creating a button with a `(click)=setHidden()` function on the MainComponent to change the MainComponent properties but nothing happens. What am I missing when it comes to the inter-component communication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hidden` is a default property. Adding an input with the same name seems to prevent the default behavior. Commenting out the input makes `hidden` work:

```
export class Child2Component {
    // @Input() hidden:boolean;
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fhslO7?p=preview)

Comment: You know a part of me wondered if using the default property might be an issue but I quickly dismissed it for no good reason. Thanks!

Comment: simple answer to a seemingly complicated question..thanks.

Comment: worth knowing even though this is not the droid I was looking for..thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is fine but `directives` has now been deprecated so if you use the code as originally stated in Angular4 then you will get an error.

As long as the child components are declared within @NgModule in the module, they no longer need to to be included in the metadata of the parent component